# Create a char array by testing the values of an int array in Java

Tags: java, arrays

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong in this code?

```
public class grades {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] testMarks = Marks.getMarks();
        System.out.print(grading(testMarks));

    }
    public static char[] grading(int[] testMarks) {

        char grade = '0';
        char[] grades = new char[grade];
        int value = 0;
        int n = 0;
            while (n < testMarks.length) {
                value = testMarks[n];
                if (value >= 90) {
                grade = 'A';
                }
                else if (value < 90 && value >= 75) {
                grade = 'B';
                }
                else if (value < 75 && value >= 60) {
                grade = 'C';
                }
                else if (value < 60 && value >= 50) {
                grade = 'D';
                }
                else if (value < 50 && value >= 45) {
                grade = 'E';
                }
                else {
                grade = 'F';
                }
                n =+ 1;
        }
        return grades;
    }
}
```

I am trying to return the values of the testMarks array as char based on the boundaries listed. I don't get any errors, but it doesn't display anything.

Cheers,
Em

Comment: That should be n += 1. And where is Marks class defined? Also, the class name should start with capital letter I guess!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to populate the grades array :) you need to:

```
grades[n] = grade;
```

before incrementing n; otherwise the grades array would be empty. Other than that, n++ would work just fine:

```
public static char[] grading(int[] testMarks) {

    char grade = '0';
    char[] grades = new char[testMarks.length];
    int value = 0;
    int n = 0;
        while (n < testMarks.length) {
            value = testMarks[n];
            if (value >= 90) {
            grade = 'A';
            }
            else if (value < 90 && value >= 75) {
            grade = 'B';
            }
            else if (value < 75 && value >= 60) {
            grade = 'C';
            }
            else if (value < 60 && value >= 50) {
            grade = 'D';
            }
            else if (value < 50 && value >= 45) {
            grade = 'E';
            }
            else {
            grade = 'F';
            }
            grades[n] = grade;
            n++;
    }
    return grades;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

- `n =+ 1` would be `n += 1`.
- `char[] grades = new char[grade]` would be `char[] grades = new char[testMarks.length]`
- before increament of n, write `grades[n] = grade`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should write n+=1 in your code

Answer (score 0):

`grades` array is always empty. You need to store the `grade` values in that array before returning. Something like this should work:

```
public static char[] grading(int[] testMarks) {

    char grade = '0';
    char[] grades = new char[testMarks.length]; // initialise with an empty char array with the same length as testMarks
    int value = 0;
    int n = 0;
    while (n < testMarks.length) {
        value = testMarks[n];
        if (value >= 90) {
            grade = 'A';
        }
        else if (value < 90 && value >= 75) {
            grade = 'B';
        }
        else if (value < 75 && value >= 60) {
            grade = 'C';
        }
        else if (value < 60 && value >= 50) {
            grade = 'D';
        }
        else if (value < 50 && value >= 45) {
            grade = 'E';
        }
        else {
            grade = 'F';
        }
        grades[n] = grade; // store the grade in the grades array
        n += 1;
    }
    return grades;
}
```